# input field value is empty when submit form after JQuery set value to the input field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list and a input field on the page using MVC.
I use JQuery to get the value from Controller to set value for this input field depends on the drop down list selection. I noticed the input field is populated on the page, but the value attribute is still empty checked using browser Developer Tool.
I use

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.inputFieldID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "inputFieldID"} })
```

In JQuery ajax I set the value like:

```
$("#inputFieldID").val(NewValueFromDB);
```

and I can see value is set using

```
alert($("#inputFieldID").val());
```

but on the page, the value attribute field is empty, what did I miss?

**UPDATE:**

I figured out that because I try to make the input field not editable, so I gave @disabled = "disabled" to it. That seems stopping the value get passed to Controller.

But my question is, if I want to make the input field not editable, but still can pass the value to Controller what should I do?

**ANSWER**
Use readonly instead of disabled attribute and give a grey background-color to make it look like not editable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `.val()` method updates the element's `value` **property** and not the attribute value.

The attribute is mainly used to initialize the property.

Normally you do not have a need for the `value` attribute of `input` elements.

See [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that because I try to make the input field not editable, so I gave @disabled = "disabled" to it. That seems stopping the value get passed to Controller.

Comment: @XiaoHan to make it not editable use the `readonly` attribute.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I have to use readonly and apply some background-color style to the input field to make it looks like not editable.